# Signing an S3 URL with a future expiration AND start date

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

We can sign a URL for S3 using the JS SDK, and set an expiration date:

```
const params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Expires: 60};
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
console.log('The URL is', url); // expires in 60 seconds
```

Can we also set a date for when the signed request would be valid?

Suppose I want to sign a URL in a way where it won't be valid until tomorrow, and then will be valid for one day.  How would I do that?  Preferably, with the JS SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3's pre-signed URLs do not offer this functionality, directly.

CloudFront does support this, if you use a [CloudFront signed URL with a custom policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html) instead.

You can create a CloudFront distribution, and connect it to the bucket with an Origin Access Identity, which allows CloudFront to authenticate itself for accessing the bucket, and then "Restrict viewer access" on the CloudFront distribution so that CloudFront only allows access when a valid signed CloudFront URL is provided.  CloudFront signed URLs require a "not after" date, but also support a "not before" date.

You'll need to use [`CloudFront.Signer.getSignedUrl()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront/Signer.html) but **do not** supply the `url` or `expires` options.  Pass only the `policy` option.

The `policy` is a JSON string containing values for `Resource`, `DateLessThan` (expiration time) and `DateGreaterThan` (before which, access the URL will be denied).  You can optionally pass `IpAddress` to limit use of this URL to a single IPv4 address or block.  IPv6-based restriction isn't supported.

It's a bit of an advanced operation, but see [these example policy statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement-examples) for the expected format.  The whitespace shown in the examples does not need to be included in the policy document.

You don't need to follow the instructions for actually signing and escaping the URL because the SDK is handling that part for you... but you'll need to create the JSON policy.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  One quick follow-up question... I stumbled on `X-Amz-Date` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html) since posting the question.  Can it be used for this purpose?

Comment: It crossed my mind that manipulating `X-Amz-Date` might be an option, but it is not as simple as *just* manipulating that. The `X-Amz-Credential` would also need to be modified, which would change the signature, and this likely gets deeper into the actual signing logic than the SDK may allow you to easily access.  I'm not certain what the granularity would be, if you took this approach.  If I were guessing, the signed URL would likely start working either ~15 minutes or ~7 days prior to `X-Amz-Date`, based on what's actually happening internally with credential rotation and timestamp checking.